# Origin of Law - Legal Philosophy

Tags: legal-history, jurisprudence

What kind of legal philosophy states that rights and duties (**law**) derive from **facts**?

(In German *SOLLEN* for the former and *SEIN* for the latter.)

Comment: I propose a new tag, f. i. 'legal method', or 'philosophy of law'.

Comment: There is a good question here, but as written it is asking for an opinion, and opinion based questions are not a good fit for the Stack Exchange model. Can you reword it?

Comment: OK, can you give me a clue, please?

Comment: Start with https://law.stackexchange.com/tour and then https://law.stackexchange.com/help for things like https://law.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask For this particular question you could turn it into "What is the name of the legal philosophy that states that rights and duties derive from facts"? or some other form that isn't subjective.

Comment: The philosophy of law is called jurisprudence.

Comment: It is (still) prudent to separate science (of law) from philosophy (of law). _Jurisprudence_ might refer to both.

Comment: Is the science of law something like the science of art? A subset of psychology and sociology?

Comment: Science of art, I would consider like _contradictio in adiecto_.  -  A 'subset'? I would look at law as an independent discipline for the time being.